# Duns Scotus' criticism of Aristotle's Modal Argument against self change

Tags: metaphysics, aristotle

Peter King [cites](http://individual.utoronto.ca/pking/articles/Scotus_on_Self-Change.pdf) Duns Scotus' presentation of the *Modal Argument* against *self change* (additions by him):

> [The Modal Argument] is taken from Phys . 3.2 [202 a 10–13], where Aristotle says “the mover moves insofar as it is in act, and the mobile is moved insofar as it is in potency, as is evident from the definition of motion given in [ Phys . 3.1 201 a 11–12].  11 However, it is impossible that the same thing be at once in potency and in act with respect to the same and according to the same. Therefore, [nothing can be moved by itself].

And then goes on to give the following restatement of it:

> The Modal Argument may be reformulated at a more general level as follows:
>
> - [A1] The subject of a change must be in potency to φ . (Definition of
>     change)
> - [A2] Causes must “contain” their effects. (Causal Axiom 1)
> - [A3] Hence the cause of a change must be in act with respect to φ . 
>     (From [A2] and the definition of change)
> - [A4] Proximate causes must be spatio-temporally concurrent with their
>     immediate effects. (Causal Axiom 2)
> - [A5] It is impossible for one and the same thing to be at once in
>     potency and act with respect to the same and according to the same. 
>     (Application of the Law of Non-Contradiction to potency and act)
>
> Therefore: Anything that changes must be changed by another.

Duns Scotus rejects the argument because of A5 and A3.

The question now is not if Duns Scotus is correct, but rather why he is not *very obviously* correct – how A5 and A3 could even be somewhat plausible rather than trivially wrong.

If we take, for example, a match and a matchbox and strike the match against the side of the matchbox, fire is produced. But why should we assume that the “form of fire” (if we grant the existence of such a form) is *in actuality* somewhere “on” the matchbox (or anywhere else)?

Can somebody give some explanation why one should not immediately discard A5 and A3? *How* could one regard them as reasonable?

Comment: Were you not satisfied by what I quoted in [my answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/41587/2014) to your question "How are 'causal' loops avoided in Aristotelian-Thomistic metaphysics?"? It seems you're asking about the "_quidquid movetur ab alio movetur_" principle again.

Comment: `But why should we assume that the “form of fire” (if we grant the existence of such a form) is in actuality somewhere “on” the matchbox (or anywhere else)` strikes me as confusing Platonic forms with Aristotle's essences...

Comment: @Geremia no, I found your answer impenetrable. If I had been satisfied by your answer, I would have accepted it. And also, the two questions are not remotely the same. It's not about causal loops this time, but about the **axiom** *“the cause of a change must be in act with respect to φ”* which one needs to exclude self change.

Comment: @Geremia so either you say something about A3 and A5, or you stay out of this discussion. It doesn't help to claim *“you've asked this question before!”* when those two questions are clearly different.

Comment: @virmaior you should go into a bit more detail. What's exactly the problem with this sentence? It can't be “form of fire” itself, that's something Aquinas and Aristotle mentioned.

Comment: For Aristotle and his followers, when a thing exists (other than an artifact), the form of the thing exists as the organizing continuous principle of the thing. So if fire is a substantial kind, then when the fire exists, that means the form exists with it.

Comment: @virmaior but I didn't write anything that would contradict your statement. The problem is that A3 claims that the form of fire already existed before the fire in the usual, obvious way existed.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats If you found my "answer impenetrable," why didn't you ask for clarification? And what's the difference between self-change and what you call "causal loops"?

Comment: @Geremia the major difference between the question about causal loops and this one is that here a special argument (the Modal Argument) against self-change is closely examined. That's a *huge* difference!

Comment: @Geremia regarding your answer to the question about causal loops: well, virmajor already asked for clarification (not that successfully). Also your answer didn't really engage with the subquestions. Granted, by the definition of a *per se* series, members act simultaneously, but do such series even exist? There is a subtle temporal ordering in an such examples, e.g. when the hand moves a stick, which moves a stone. And you've also made tons of unjustified assumptions in your answer, which you probably noticed, e.g. that *per se* series must be hierarchically ordered.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats What's an example of "_per se_ series" that is not "hierarchically ordered"?

Comment: @Geremia pretty much anything involving actio et reactio. Simple example: A harmonic oscillator consisting of two masses connected with a spring floating in space: how should the hierarchy look like in this case?

Answer (score 2):

In Duns Scotus' philosophy some forms are active principles and have the power to produce an effect. There are two kind of powers *qua* efficient causes, *natura* and *voluntas*, But he distinguishes between the *aptitudo* and the *excercitio* of those powers. Talking about natural efficient powers, a form can have an apptitude but no excecises it because theres no subjet in potency near to activate her. So a form can be in actuallity on a subject by way of apptitude.